# How to declare shorthand key for section/subsection?

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs, shorthands

I am now writing a file with many section, subsection, subsubsections.
I wish to declare a new shorthand for this.

---

Perhaps something like:  \s, \ss, \sss for section, subsection, susubsection, and with an n for the *-versions.

For example

- \sssn{} = \subsubsection*{}
- \ss{}= \subsection{}

---

How does one go about setting this?

Comment: Are you familiar with LaTeX's `\newcommand` macro?

Comment: To solve quickly: `\let\foo\section` , `\let\bah\subsection`, etc.,  but be completely sure that  `\foo` and  `\bah`  are not already defined as `\par` or `\emph`,  or the  result could be amusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two distinct approaches to achieving your objective.

First, you could issue a number of `\newcommand` directives to create macros called `\s`, `\ss`, `\sss`, and their "starred" counterparts `\sn`, `\ssn`, and `\sssn`:

```
% Must un-define "\ss" first:
\let\ss\relax
% The unstarred commands take one optional argument:
\newcommand\s[2][]{\section[#1]{#2}}
\newcommand\ss[2][]{\subsection[#1]{#2}}
\newcommand\sss[2][]{\subsubsection[#1]{#2}}
% The starred commands take a single, mandatory argument:
\newcommand\sn[1]{\section*{#1}}
\newcommand\ssn[1]{\subsection*{#1}}
\newcommand\sssn[1]{\subsubsection*{#1}}
```

to write things like `\s[abbr form]{full form}` and `\ssn{full form}`.

Second, you could pursue an abbreviated setup via TeX's `\let` primitive:

```
% Must un-define "\ss" first:
\let\ss\relax
% Using TeX's "\let" primitive:
\let\s\section
\let\ss\subsection
\let\sss\subsubsection
```

to write things such as `\s[abbr form]{full form}` and `\ss*{full form}`.

Either way, it's essential to undefine an existing macro called `\ss`. If you have reason to believe that you may need to typeset the character `ß` in your document and don't have  way to enter it directly on your keyboard, you should definitely save the default meaning of `\ss` via, say, `\let\ssorig\ss` *before* undefining it.